# Not receiving an email from Apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, email, custom

I've designed a very basic trigger that is meant to send me an email when a financial field on Opportunities is not blank.  The code has no errors, and when I run my test class, it achieves 100% pass.  However, when I go to test this out live, I never receive an email.    I played around with After Insert and Before Update, but no dice.  I'm not sure where else to look - help!

Code:

```
trigger FinancialErrorAssistant on Opportunity (after update) {
     //Trigger should continue only if the Financial sync error field is blank. 
     List <opportunity> Finance_Info = [Select Id, Finance_Sync_Error__c, AccountId, Bill_To_Account__c
                      From Opportunity];

    if(opportunity.Finance_Sync_Error__c != NULL){
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'MyEmail@gmail.com'};
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setReplyTo('NoReply@Salesforce.com');
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
        mail.setPlainTextBody('A wild Finance error appears! ' + Finance_Sync_Error__c );
    }    
}
```

P.S.  I know my governor limits are not on point, still learning!

Comment: are you running this in Sandbox. Then set email deliverability to ALL email.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, it's already set to "All".   

 But thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: did you check debug and email invocation in debug And where do you declare this Opportunity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to actually call `Messaging.sendEmail`. For example:

```
Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> { mail });
```

In regards to governor limits, you only get 10 invocations of the above method in a single transaction, so just call the send method outside any loops. You can build the list and then send the emails once the list is complete.

Comment: -Head Desk-  Wow.  I can't believe I just spent two hours looking at this and didn't even call the process, amateur mistake.  

Thank you, it works!

Comment: @DanielSassone Glad I could help! Don't forget, if this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green.

Comment: I absolutely will!  It has a time limit on it before I can accept it.

Comment: Gotcha. I thought it was ten minutes, but I guess I was wrong and it's actually fifteen. Cheers!